# How to plot each bar with different colour using MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

I have got the 8 colour code for bar chart in MATLAB but I need more. How it is possible?

the first bar in attached image getting two colours, why it is happening, please inform me make it with a single colour.

MatLab code:

```
ei_with_plvei = categorical({'[14]', '[31]', '[36]', '[45]', '[08]', '[09]', '[10]', '[11]', '[13]', 'test1', 'test2'});
x_axis = ei_with_plvei; 
y_axis = [67.47 78.04 50.81 57.58 79.53 80.53 70.43 74.73 77.81 95 97];
figure, 
bar(x_axis, y_axis);
hold on;
bar(x_axis(1),y_axis(1));
set(bar(1),'FaceColor','b');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(2),y_axis(2));
set(bar(2),'FaceColor','r');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(3),y_axis(3));
set(bar(3),'FaceColor','g');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(4),y_axis(4));
set(bar(4),'FaceColor','c');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(5),y_axis(5));
set(bar(5),'FaceColor','m');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(6),y_axis(6));
set(bar(6),'FaceColor','y');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(7),y_axis(7));
set(bar(7),'FaceColor','k');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(8),y_axis(8));
set(bar(8),'FaceColor','w');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(9),y_axis(9));
set(bar(9),'FaceColor','m');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(10),y_axis(10));
set(bar(10),'FaceColor','m');
hold on;
bar(x_axis(11),y_axis(11));
set(bar(11),'FaceColor','m');
```

output: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First bar is getting two bars because of the `set(bar(1),....)`. This returns the handle of the newly created bar with height 1. `set(bar(2),....)` returns the handle of the newly created bar with height 2, etc.

Furthermore, calling `hold on` once is sufficient. Then the setting is set.

As with regards to color, you can use

- [RGB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html): `bar(x_axis(11),y_axis(11),'FaceColor',[1 1 0.5]);` or
- [Hexadecimal](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/458086-how-to-specify-line-color-using-a-hexadecimal-color-code): `bar(x_axis(10),y_axis(10),'FaceColor','#FF60F0');`

So example of working code:

```
ei_with_plvei = categorical({'[14]', '[31]', '[36]', '[45]', '[08]', '[09]', '[10]', '[11]', '[13]', 'test1', 'test2'});
    x_axis = ei_with_plvei; 
    y_axis = [67.47 78.04 50.81 57.58 79.53 80.53 70.43 74.73 77.81 95 97];
    figure, 
    bar(x_axis, y_axis);
    hold on;
    bar(x_axis(1),y_axis(1),'FaceColor','b');
    bar(x_axis(2),y_axis(2),'FaceColor','r');
    bar(x_axis(3),y_axis(3),'FaceColor','g');
    bar(x_axis(4),y_axis(4),'FaceColor','c');
    bar(x_axis(5),y_axis(5),'FaceColor','m');
    bar(x_axis(6),y_axis(6),'FaceColor','y');
    bar(x_axis(7),y_axis(7),'FaceColor','k');
    bar(x_axis(8),y_axis(8),'FaceColor','w');
    bar(x_axis(9),y_axis(9),'FaceColor','m');
    bar(x_axis(10),y_axis(10),'FaceColor','#FF60F0');
    bar(x_axis(11),y_axis(11),'FaceColor',[1 1 0.5]);
```

Comment: And if you do `col = {'b', 'r', ... , [1 1 0.5]}` then you simply use a for loop, `for i = 1:11;bar(x_axis(i),y_axis(i),'FaceColor',col{i}),end`.